# powershell wmi to html duplicate objects- and how i add drive letters with wmi?

Tags: html, powershell, wmi

i create this startup script for send me system info and get all the properties 3 times now when i have 3 partitions on the machine:

```vbs
$hostname = $env:computername

$file1 = "\\**UNC***\$hostname.1.csv"
$file2 = "\\*****UNC*******\$hostname.2.csv"

$compinfo = @()
$computerSystem = get-wmiobject Win32_ComputerSystem 
$computerBIOS = get-wmiobject Win32_BIOS 
$computerOS = get-wmiobject Win32_OperatingSystem 
$computerCPU = get-wmiobject Win32_Processor 
$computerHDD = Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter drivetype=3 
$colItems = Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter "IpEnabled = TRUE"
# Build objects
ForEach($HDD in $computerHDD){
    $compinfo += New-Object PSObject -property @{ 
        PCName = $computerSystem.Name 
        Manufacturer = $computerSystem.Manufacturer 
        Model = $computerSystem.Model 
        SerialNumber = $computerBIOS.SerialNumber 
        RAM = "{0:N2}" -f ($computerSystem.TotalPhysicalMemory/1GB) 
        HDDSize = "{0:N2}" -f ($HDD.Size/1GB) 
        HDDFree = "{0:P2}" -f ($HDD.FreeSpace/$HDD.Size) 
        CPU = $computerCPU.Name 
        OS = $computerOS.caption 
        SP = $computerOS.ServicePackMajorVersion 
        User = $computerSystem.UserName 
        BootTime = $computerOS.ConvertToDateTime($computerOS.LastBootUpTime) 
        IP_Address = [string]$colItems.IpAddress 
        MAC_Address = [string]$colItems.MacAddress 
        Default_Gateway = [string]$colItems.DefaultIpGateway 
        DNS_Domain = $colItems.DNSDomain 
        DHCP_Enabled = $colItems.DHCPEnabled 
    }
}

#wmi for windows updates

$Session = New-Object -ComObject "Microsoft.Update.Session"
$Searcher = $Session.CreateUpdateSearcher()
$historyCount = $Searcher.GetTotalHistoryCount()
$Searcher.QueryHistory(0, $historyCount) | Select-Object Title, Description, Date | Export-Csv $file2 -NoTypeInformation

$hotfix1 = Import-Csv $file1
$hotfix2 = Import-Csv $file2

#Styles:

#Updates Style
$style = @"
<h3>Installed Updates:</h3>
<style>
"TABLE{border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse;}
TH {border: 1px solid black; background: #B0E0E0; padding: 5px; }
TD {border: 1px solid black; padding: 5px; }





</style>
"@

#services Style
$style2 = @"
<h3>Services Report:</h3>
<style>
"TABLE{border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse;}
TH {border: 1px solid black; background: #B0E0E0; padding: 5px; }
TD {border: 1px solid black; padding: 5px; }





</style>
"@



# style for system info

$style4 = @"
<h3>System info:</h3>
<style>
"TABLE{border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse;}
TH {border: 1px solid black; background: #B0E0E0; padding: 5px; }
TD {border: 1px solid black; padding: 5px; }





</style>
"@






#check to see if first time running script by the old file.
$oldfile = "\\******UNC****\$hostname.old.csv"
$TestPath = Test-Path $oldfile

                If (!$TestPath) {
                $text = "First time script on this machine.. cant get updates status"

}
Else
{
$text = "No updates are installed!"
}

#this style is when no updates found or first time script run.
$style3 = @"
<h3>Installed Updates:</h3>
<p>$text</p>






</style>
"@






$Compare = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $hotfix2 -DifferenceObject $hotfix1 -Property Title, Description, Date | Select-Object Title, Description, Date

$Service = Get-Service | Select-Object Name, DisplayName, Status | Sort-Object status -Descending

$compinfo | select -Property HDDFree ,HDDSize ,Ram ,OS ,CPU ,SP ,IP_Address,Mac_Address ,BootTime ,DHCP_Enabled

#Send Mail:

$smtpServer = "*****"
$smtpFrom = "**********"
$smtpTo = "**************"
$messageSubject = "$hostname has been started!"

$message = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage $smtpfrom, $smtpto
$message.Subject = $messageSubject
$message.IsBodyHTML = $true




                If ($compare -eq $null) {
                $Compare = ConvertTo-Html -Head $style3
                    $message.Body = $Compare
                    $message.Body += $Service | ConvertTo-Html -Head $style2
                    $message.Body += $cominfovar | ConvertTo-Html -As Table -Head $style4
}
                Else 
{
                    $message.Body = $Compare | ConvertTo-Html -Head $style
                    $message.Body += $Service | ConvertTo-Html -Head $style2
                    $message.Body += $cominfovar | ConvertTo-Html -As Table -Head $style4
}






$smtp = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer)
$smtp.Send($message)

  #Remove Old Files

del "\\*****UNC******\$hostname.old.csv"
Rename-Item $file1 "\\**********UNC*********\$hostname.old.csv"
Rename-Item $file2 $file1
```

i post all of the script ( im sure i have alot of mstakes im new in powershell)
what the solution for the duplicate properties in the table output?
can you please help me add drive letters in system info?
any upgrades for the script will be helpful, like other useful system info...

Answer (score 0):

Your `foreach` loop runs for each logical disk (i.e. partition/volume) in your computer:

```psh
$computerHDD = Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter drivetype=3 
...
ForEach($HDD in $computerHDD){
    $compinfo += ...
}
```

The output should report the size (and free space) of each partition, though. The property `DeviceID` will give you the drive letter assigned to the logical disk.

If you want the size of the physical disk(s) rather than the size of the partitions you need to query the [`Win32_DiskDrive`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394132%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) class instead. Note, however, that this class doesn't provide free disk space information, because it doesn't know anything about files or the space they use.

Comment: Thanks i will add this to the script